# Использование "многие ко многим" или использовать json в столбце и хранить ключи в другой таблице?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

У меня есть таблица расписание "schedule", тип недели "type_week" и группы "groups".
Как будет правильно и удобно сделать если, мне нужно будет проверять типы недели и группу на то что они как бы заняты. Или брать json из строки и таблицу и проверять? (Для web приложения) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Практически олнозначно линковочная таблица. JSON оправдан лишь в случае, когда он передаётся целиком как есть куда-то дальше.

Comment: @Akina обработка json сервером (php) не целесообразно получается?